# HPA Scaling even though Current CPU is below Target CPU

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cpu-usage, hpa

I am playing around with the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler in Kubernetes. I've set the HPA to start up new instances once the average CPU Utilization passes 35%. However this does not seem to work as expected.
The HPA triggers a rescale even though the CPU Utilization is far below the defined target utilization. As seen below the "current" utilization is 10% which is far away from 35%. But still, it rescaled the number of pods from 5 to 6.
[image]

I've also checked the metrics in my Google Cloud Platform dashboard (the place at which we host the application). This also shows me that the requested CPU utilization hasn't surpassed the threshold of 35%. But still, several rescales occurred.
[image]

The content of my HPA

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
 name: django
spec:
{{ if eq .Values.env "prod" }}
 minReplicas: 5
 maxReplicas: 35
{{ else if eq .Values.env "staging" }}
 minReplicas: 1
 maxReplicas: 3
{{ end }}
 scaleTargetRef:
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   name: django-app
 targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 35
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this might be?

Comment: Did you specify any cpu/memory limits in your pods? That percentage is an avarage of all pods, but are bounded to the limits. If you specify a limit of "500m" for cpu, your 35% will be inside this "50%" limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes HPA wrong metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811207/kubernetes-hpa-wrong-metrics)

Comment: @HectorVido yes i've defined a limit for the pods. It currently is set to the following:
    `limits:
      cpu: 400m
      memory: 700Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 350Mi`

I don't quite get what you mean by "If you specify a limit of "500m" for cpu, your 35% will be inside this "50%" limit."

Comment: If you specify `cpu: 400m` that means that your pod can only access 40% of a core. When you specify `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 35` you asking to scale when pod are consuming `140m` or 14% of a core.

Comment: @HectorVido After doing some additional research I think that I finally got it. The targetCPUUtilizationPercentage scales when the average CPU utilization of a deployment surpasses 35% it's configured "requests" value. So in the case of CPU requests: 200m an autoscale will trigger once it hits 70m or 7% of a core.

Comment: Yes man! I'll write an answer here just to clarify for other people.

Comment: If its one pod @HectorVido answer holds well. "TargetUtilizationPercentage" is a "mean" of all Pods in that namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky and can be a bug, but I don't think so, most of time people configure too low values as I'll explain.

#### How `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` relates to Pod's resources `requests`.

The `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` configures a percentage based on the required CPU that a pod has specified. On Kubernetes we can't create an `HPA` without specifying `requests` to CPU. It also makes sense to add some limits, because most of the time we don't want to use all available physical CPU.

Let's assume that this is our `requests`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: apache
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apache
      image: httpd:alpine
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1000m
```

And in our `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` inside HPA we specify 75%.

That is easy to explain because we ask for 100% *(1000m = 1 CPU core)* of a single core, so when this core is about 75% of use, HPA will start to work.

But if we define our `requests` as this:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apache
      image: httpd:alpine
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 500m
```

Now, 100% of CPU our pod has specified is only 50% of a single core. Fine, so 100% of cpu resource usage from this pod means, on hardware, 50% usage of a single core.

This is indifferent for `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage`, if we keep our value of `75%` the HPA will start to work when our single core is about `37.5%` usage, because this is 75% of all CPU this `pod` requested.

From the perspective of a pod/hpa, they never know that they are limited on CPU or memory.

#### Understanding the scenario in the question above

With some programs like the one used in the question above - *the CPU spikes do occur* - however only in small timeframes *(for example 10 second spikes)*. Due to the short duration of these spikes the metric server doesn't save this spike, but only saves the metric after a 1m window. In such cases the spike in between such windows will be excluded. This explains why the spike cannot be seen in the metrics dashboards, but is picked up by the HPA.

Thus, for services with *low cpu resources/limits* a larger scale-up time window *(`scaleUp` settings in HPA)* can be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am starting to suspect that something is going wrong with the metrics. I've been testing it with a different setup. The HPA looks as following: https://snipboard.io/we892C.jpg the limits and requests have been setup as following: https://snipboard.io/AtsiLW.jpg. However when I look at the CPU utilization of the service it doesn't come close to the specified target https://snipboard.io/QTlfpr.jpg. What do you think?

Comment: How are you testing (stressing) the application? But, you should look to `limits` not `requests`. The `requests` specify only a minimum necessary of a resource to a pod be scheduled on a node.

Comment: The application is being used by clients. Also when I look at the Average CPU limit utilization of the pods, it's way below the target: https://snipboard.io/OiTFtc.jpg

Comment: Okay, but can this mean that the application is working well and there is no reason to scale it up, or not?

Comment: In this case I do not expect it to scale up, but yet it does trigger scale ups. The reason for implementing this is that we expect a growth in the amount of clients, and therefore want to be ready for this by being able to autoscale on traffic peaks. The problem now is that the HPA is scaling the application, even tough the CPU target is not being reached yet. Several autoscales occur every hour whilst the CPU levels are below target (sometimes even to 15 or more replicas). So the HPA at this moment is not working as I expected and I don't quite understand why it's triggering upscales.

Comment: Script applications (Python, PHP, Perl) can have a lot of spikes just to load the framework files on each request, and the metrics server only keep the last metric in memory. Try to put a larger limit, like `1000m` and watch. Also, take a look on HPA `scaleUp` settigs, maybe you can define a larger window to scale.

Comment: That explains it. So just to confirm: The CPU spikes do occur, however only in small timeframes (for example 10 second spikes). Due to the short duration of these spikes the metric server doesn't save this spike, but only saves the metric after 1m in which the spike will be excluded. Which would explain why the spike cannot be seen in the metrics, but is picked up by the HPA. Is this correct?

Comment: Its is possible, yes. A larger time window in scaling up services with low cpu limits can help.

Comment: Hi Hector, I made a script which gathers the CPU utilization metrics every 10 seconds. You were right, the CPU spikes occur within small timeframes (sometimes 10/20 seconds). That explains why it was not shown in the metrics. Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: This seems wrong? This answers says it references 'limits' but the docs and other answers say 'requests' so which is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Since my answer also explain about the difficult to extract the current value I will edit it.

Answer (score 9):

Scaling is based on % of `requests` not `limits`. I think we should change this answer as the examples in the accepted answer show:

```
 limits:
   cpu: 1000m
```

But the `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` is based on `requests` like:

```
requests:
   cpu: 1000m
```

> For per-pod resource metrics (like CPU), the controller fetches the metrics from the resource metrics API for each Pod targeted by the HorizontalPodAutoscaler. Then, if a target utilization value is set, the controller calculates the utilization value as a percentage of the equivalent resource request on the containers in each Pod. If a target raw value is set, the raw metric values are used directly. The controller then takes the mean of the utilization or the raw value (depending on the type of target specified) across all targeted Pods, and produces a ratio used to scale the number of desired replicas.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-a-horizontalpodautoscaler-work

Comment: You are right, since my answer also explains why is difficult to capture that metric, I fixed all my references of  "limits" do "requests".